# Wrong type of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple javascript/jquery function that looks like this:

```js
$("#add_a, #add_b").on("change keyup paste", function () {
        var add_a = $('#add_a').val(),
            add_b = $('#add_b').val(),

            add = add_a + add_b;

            $("#add").text(add);
    });
```

The problem is that it treats the variables add_a and add_b as strings even though i get the value from a input with type="number". I have made other similar functions and haven't had this problem before!

To making it clear, if I type in 3 in #add_a and 4 in #add_b the result is 34 and not 7.

Is there a way to make sure it get the values as numbers or change it after?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `type="number"` just affects what values can be entered and allows the browser to try to enhance the appearance of the element. It doesn't change the type of the `<input>`'s [`.value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties), which is always a `DOMString` (or `String`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, values from `<input>`s are treated as strings.  You need to parse them as a number, for that, you can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var add_a = parseInt($('#add_a').val(), 10),
    add_b = parseInt($('#add_b').val(), 10)
```

If you're expecting non-integer input, you can use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) and parse the value as an Integer. If an Integer is what you want...